# vba + write values to dynamic one-dimensional array and write to csv file

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, csv

I have a problem writing an array to a .csv file. I found a way to create an array and to write it to a .csv file, but it gives an error @(arrayNumber(i) = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value). I can't find why I can't write these values into the array. Because of this problem I also couldn't test if the writing to the .Csv file is the correct way. I hope someone can point me into the right direction. thanks in advance.

```
Sub Numbering()

Dim arrayNumber()
Dim arrayName()

Dim pathName As String

If ActiveSheet.Name = "OVERVIEW" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Template" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Develop" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Schedule" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Information" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Announcements" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Database" Then
    MsgBox ("You can't extract the number and name to a csv file.")

Else

    pathName = "C:" & "\textfile.csv"
    Open pathName For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Number   Name"

    ActiveSheet.Select
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("K1048555").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim Preserve arrayNumber(1 To LastRow)
    ReDim Preserve arrayName(1 To LastRow)

    j = 1
    For i = 13 To LastRow

            If ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "1" Then
                arrayNumber(i) = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                arrayName(i) = ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & i).Value
                Print #1, " arrayNumber & "; " & arrayName"
                j = j + 1
            End If
    Next
    Close #1
    MsgBox ("Done")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With some trying I have found the solution (code below).

```
Sub Numbering()

Dim arrayNumber()
Dim arrayName()

Dim pathName As String

If ActiveSheet.Name = "OVERVIEW" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Template" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Develop" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Schedule" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Information" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Announcements" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Database" Then
    MsgBox ("You can't extract the number and name to a csv file.")

Else

    pathName = "C:" & "\textfile.csv"
    Open pathName For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Number   Name"

    ActiveSheet.Select
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("K1048555").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim Preserve arrayNumber(1 To LastRow)
    ReDim Preserve arrayName(1 To LastRow)

    j = 1
    For i = 13 To LastRow

            If ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "1" Then
               arrayNumber(j) = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
                arrayName(j) = ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & i).Value

                MsgBox (arrayNumber(j))
                MsgBox (arrayName(j))
                Print #1, arrayNumber(j) & "; " & arrayName(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
    Next
    Close #1
    MsgBox ("Done")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you migth consider:

```
Sub M_snb()
  createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").createtextfile("C:\textfile.csv").write join([transpose(if(K13:K2000="","",A13:A2000&";"&K13:K2000))],vbcrlf)
end sub
```